# How to wrap an R function that accepts a scalar so it will accept a vector?

Tags: r

I have a function in R that accepts a scalar value quite nicely, but it doesn't accept a vector.

Is there any way to place a wrapper over it, so this wrapper function can accept a vector?

The function itself has 5 parameters.

**What I've tried**

I've tried every combination of `sapply`, `lapply` and `mapply` I can think of, and R keeps on giving errors that are somewhat obscure, to say the least.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, this works perfectly! If you submit this as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.

The original function call is:

```
result<-MyFunc(P=34,S=100,X=100,T=1)
```

**Method 1**

To make this accept a vector input, simply add `mapply` in front of the function call and convert the first opening bracket `(` into a comma `,`:

```
result<-mapply(MyFunc,P=34,S=100,X=100,T=1)
```

**Method 2**

Thanks to @Roland, type `??Vectorize` to find a function that can wrap a function to make it accept vectors.

```
MyFuncOnVector <- Vectorize(MyFunc)
result <- MyFuncOnVector(P=34,S=100,X=100,T=1)
```

Behind the scenes, Vectorize is calling `mapply`.